# why does high speed current follows the path of least inductance? and how are the shape of lines are different at low and high speed?

Tags: digital-logic, pcb-layers, system

Does anybody know why the lines of electromagnetic field at high speed are bent and exactly following the shape of line, while in the low speed device the electromagnetic lines[image] are in the usual propagation shape.

Comment: What is "speed" of electrical current?

Comment: Please cite the source of your illustrations. I'm curious as to the context of them.

Comment: See http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/3_11.htm and http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/news/8_08.htm

Comment: OK, swap 'speed' with 'frequency'. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is a simplification, but is the best description I have seen.

First of all, "return current follows the path of least resistance" is actually a bit misleading.

The **current returns by any and all means that it can**. The path of "least resistance", or more accurately "path of least impedance", simply carries more current than any other path. However that may not be the majority of the current. That is, the path of least resistance may carry 25% of the current but all the other paths may carry 75% in total.

This is actually true regardless of the signal frequency.

However, each wire can be represented by the image below. Each point along the wire has a capacitance to the ground plane (Or to ground or whatever else is in the vicinity.)

[image]

As you know, with a DC signal those capacitors have no effect and can be ignored.

However, lets imagine a rising edge on a signal running down this line. As it passes each capacitor the voltage on the bottom end of the capacitor briefly jumps up to some fraction of the signal voltage.

Electrons are immediately drawn into the capacitor from the plane to charge the capacitor. When the signal reverses, the opposite is true.

These capacitances cause signal loss of course, but also has the effect of creating a potential well, or gulley in the plane which effectively becomes the new path of least impedance.

Comment: Thank you! the model you described looks like the distributed model of wire. your respond answered another question of mine :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1) those are **NOT** the electromagnetic field lines. Read the text, the lines show the **current path** meaning, the path which the returning current will take to close the current loop.

2) low frequency and DC currents just take the path of lowest resistance. They cannot take shortcuts by capacitive coupling nor are low frequency and DC signals affected by any inductance.

3) high frequency signals follow the path of lowest **impedance**, this **can** be a different path than the lowest resistance path (it **can** be different, it does not have to be). The reason for following the shortest path is that is will have the **lowest inductance** and therefore also the **lowest impedance**. High frequency signals can couple between two conductors as two isolated conductors behave as a **capacitor**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! obviously i had a huge misunderstanding about the lines! current-lines! thanks! Is it correct that at high speed the driver and resistor are acting like a capacitor and that is why the current path looks like piece wise? the path at high speed is more linear and straight, where as at low speed the current path is more oval. i want to know what's the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

As other answer have mentioned, those lines are not the electromagnetic fields lines but rather current density lines for the returning path of the current.

Generalized current will return through the path of least impedance.
In the DC cases the path of least impedance tends to be the least resistive path which is usually the shortest distance path

In high frequency cases you the current will follow the path again of least impedance which is the path that creates the smallest amount of impedance. For inductive looking paths this path tends to be the path that creates the loop with the smallest area.

So for example, in the picture you have shown even the notice the in the low speed case even though there returning path in shorter the area of the loop is bigger than the high speed case and therefore more inductive. At high frequency the shortest return path will have more impedance than going the long way around of following the resistor shape.

Additionally , in high frequency cases you will have capacitive coupling which would find shortcuts for the current in places that have a capacitance (actual capacitor like decoupling or parasitics) which will offer the path of least impedance.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. So you basically mean that the lines starting from driver are current lines choosing to go through the least impedance, that I understand. But It is not still clear to me for example why at high speed the current line is not a straight line from point x to x? why is it curvier at low speed? and more like piece wised at high speed?

Comment: Because at high speed the straight line point is more inductive and at high speeds the main source of impedance is inductance. The geometry of that path makes it more inductive. Basically the least inductive path is the one that reduces the overall area of the loop of the path taken by the current

Answer (score 0):

Nature seeks to minimize the energy required.

At DC, all possible paths get explored.

At approximately 50,000 Hertz, even as all possible paths still get explored, the inductance and the ability of large enclosed areas to store energy in that inductance, and the need for physical systems to minimize the required energy, causes all of that concurrent exploration to prefer paths with minimal enclosed area. The non-preferred (high stored energy) paths are still explored but minimal energy is stored thus minimal interference occurs.

Thus coax cables begin to be effective in herding the electrons, at 50KHz.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is as follows:

At high frequencies, ground plane impedance(**Z ≈ jwL**) and from the definition of loop inductance, the total loop inductance for two conductors with opposite directions is:

**Lt = L1 + L2 - 2M**

Where **L1** and **L2** are the partial self-inductance of the two conductors and **M** is the partial mutual-inductance between them.

If the two conductors are identical then:

**Lt = 2(L - M)**

Then, **for the return current path to have the least inductance**, it will try to have **M** as high as possible.

As a result of that, the return current path will try to follow and be very close to the signal trace as possible, hence, more **M** and less **Lt** will get.